# Vue.js Trying to use props in style

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to use some props in a component of mine that show different v-icons and sizes depending on the values passed to it.

However when i try use one of the props to set the icon size with styles the icon doesnt change at all

Heres the code:

```
<template>
    <div v-if="this.name === 'someName'">
        <v-icon :style="style" >some-icon-name</v-icon>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
        <v-icon :style="style"  >some-other-icon-name</v-icon>
    </div>
</template>

export default {

  computed: {
    style () {
      return 'size: ' + this.iconSize + ';'
    }
  },
  props: {
    iconSize: {
        type: Number,
        required: false
    },
    name : {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
  },

  data () {
    return {
      //
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

When using the component i simply use v-bind to pass the props:

```
<appIcons v-bind:iconSize="90" v-name="someName" />
```

Comment: `style` is for setting CSS styles directly. `size` is not a valid CSS property. Do you mean `font-size`? Or perhaps you're trying to pass the `size` prop of `v-icon`?

Comment: i want to set size for v-icon

Comment: that should work so long as the syntax of your `style` is valid css. Also, make sure you include `px` or `em`!. `style() { return \`font-size: ${this.iconSize}px\`  }`

Comment: it didnt work, apperently v-icon doesnt accept fontsize. only size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confusing two things. `v-icon` has a prop called `size` whereas `style` is a Vue mechanism for setting custom CSS styles. Either could be used in this case. You cannot set a `style` of `size`, that's meaningless as `size` is not a CSS property.

I think what you want is this:

```html
<v-icon :size="iconSize" >some-icon-name</v-icon>
```

That's using the `size` prop of `v-icon` rather than a custom `style`.

You could in theory do it using a `style` if you set the `font-size`. e.g.

```js
style () {
    return 'font-size: ' + this.iconSize + 'px'
}
```

Or perhaps using an object instead:

```js
style () {
    return {
       fontSize: this.iconSize + 'px'
    }
}
```